# Unable to activate calabash-android-0.9.5, because json-2.1.0 conflicts with json (~> 1.8) (Gem::ConflictError)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, calabash-android

## Getting the following error - Unable to activate calabash-android, json conflict

C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2325:in `raise_if_conflicts'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in`activate'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:224:in `rescue in try_activate'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:217:in`try_activate'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in`require'
C:/Users/Sathish/Documents/tut/features/support/env.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:94:in`load'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:94:in `load_code_file'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:237:in`load_file'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:97:in `block in load_files!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:96:in`each'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:96:in `load_files!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:242:in`load_step_definitions'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:65:in `run!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:38:in`execute!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in`load'

## C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `'

In my gem list for json it shows

`json (default: 2.1.0, 1.8.6)`

Tried uninstalling gem json 2.1.0
but that's default, won't be able to uninstall, 
Uninstalled 1.8.0 but then i got 
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:312:in `to_specs': Could not find 'json' (~> 1.8) - did find: [json-2.1.0] (Gem::MissingSpecVersio
nError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=C:/Users/Sathish/.gem/ruby/2.5.0;C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0', execute`gem env` for more information

Any help..?

Answer (score 0):

As the main gem you're trying to use has that outdated dependency, the simplest option is probably to avoid the built-in too-new `json` gem by installing and using Ruby 2.3 instead.

Comment: thanks :) Worked :) I downgraded ruby to 2.3 & uninstalled unwanted versions of gems & kept only required.